# SPNO momentary rocker switch - purpose of 3rd terminal?

Tags: switches

I am trying to solve a mystery with a coffee grinding appliance I purchased from a European company. It is made for the U.S. market (120v), and at its core is a simple motor controlled by what I *thought* was a SPNO momentary rocker switch. I would like to replace this switch with a SPST switch so I do not have to stand at the device in order for it to run.

The mystery is that this switch has 3 terminals, one of which has the neutral wire connected. This is NOT a lighted switch, so I do not understand why the neutral is connected at all. The 3 wires to the switch are:

-120v (+) in from power cord

-120v (-) in from power cord

-120v (+) out to device internals

Anyone have any ideas?

The 1st picture below shows the terminals. You can only see 2 of the 3 terminals clearly, but the wires are as follows:

-upper black wire with ivory terminal clip = 120v power in

-directly below upper black wire is brown wire = 120v power out when momentary switch is activated

-lower white wire with translucent terminal clip and jumper terminal for black neutral wire to appliance = neutral in

2nd picture is to show all switch markings. I have searched and cannot find a similar switch online anywhere. I thought I'd located a Marquardt switch (1551.3202) that was the same, but it only has 2 terminals. Any help to explain this 3rd terminal is appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One intention might be, that in the off state the normally closed part of the switch may shortcut the motor to force a hard break.

Comment: I will have to research that a bit more, as I am not 100% clear what effect that would have, nor why that would require a neutral connected to the switch. If the switch is in a normally open state, isn't the supply to the motor already "broken"?

Can you clarify what you mean by "hard break"?